# NodeJS, connect-mongo. Clear sessions and logging out another user via server code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session

I am searching through the web for logging out **another connected user** via server API but it seems that everything is about logging out the current user.

Currently, I am using `req.session.destroy()` but it only destroys the current session.

I am trying to write an API to destroy the session of another connected user from a click on my management screen.

Can some kind souls guide me please? Thank you so much!

Cheers

Comment: have you tried with this--> req.session = null;

Comment: @Dineshaws, req.session = null clear the session that you are in, but not the session of another person.